# How do I add additional fields to a text file from another text file with some matching fields?

Tags: text-processing

file1

```
A   P
B   Q
A   Q
C   R
C   P
D   S
E   T
```

file2

```
A   X1
C   X2
Q   X3
R   X4
T   X5
```

output file

```
A   X1  P
B       Q   X3    
A   X1  Q   X3
C   X2  R   X4
C   X2  P   
D       S   
E       T   X5
```

Comment: You could try [`join`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/join.html) but this is a tricky use case.  It's trivially easy with SQL, though.  If you can use SQL for this you should.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat file1
A   P
B   Q
A   Q
C   R
C   P
D   S
E   T
$ cat file2
A   X1
C   X2
Q   X3
R   X4
T   X5
$ awk -v OFS='\t' 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} {print $1, a[$1], $2, a[$2]}' file2 file1
A   X1  P   
B       Q   X3
A   X1  Q   X3
C   X2  R   X4
C   X2  P   
D       S   
E       T   X5
$
```